# MySQLi query a specific date in DATETIME field

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query all records for a specific date. Right now, I am using:

```
$date = '2016-01-30';
$query = $db->select("SELECT ID, OrderDate FROM store_orders WHERE OrderDate >= '$date 00:00:00' && OrderDate <= '$date 23:59:59'");
```

Is there a better/more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MySQL [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function for this:

```
SELECT ID, OrderDate FROM store_orders WHERE DATE(OrderDate) = '$date'
```

The `DATE` function returns just the date part of a datetime field.